# Using variables inside the for loop in shell

Tags: shell-script, variable, for

I'd like to use variables inside the for loop in shell.

My current code:

```
VAA="1st_first"
VAB="2nd_second"
VAC="3rd_third"

for i in VAA VAB VAC; do
       if [[ "${i}" =~ ^[A-Za-z]*$ ]]; then
              echo "$i variable is a word"
       else
              echo "$i variable is not a word"
       fi
done
```

The expected result would be checking the $VAR1, $VAR2, and $VAR3 variables, then print that it's a word.

The current output is:

```
VAA variable is a word
VAB variable is a word
VAC variable is a word
```

It's not correct, because the "$VAA" is contains a number.

How can I use variables from outside of for loop?

Comment: Or, depending on what exactly you're doing, use `for i in "$VAA" "$VAB" "$VAC"; do`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually solve thing like this with associative arrays. But I do not know if this is an efficient solution. But this does not guarantee the original order as it looks in the output

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A varCheck
varCheck=( [VAA]="stfirst" [VAB]="2nd_second" [VAC]="3rd_third" )


for var in ${!varCheck[@]}; do
       if [[ "${varCheck[$var]}" =~ ^[A-Za-z]*$ ]]; then
              echo "${var} variable is a word"
       else
              echo "${var} variable is not a word"
       fi
done
```

Output:

```
VAB variable is not a word
VAC variable is not a word
VAA variable is a word
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use variable indirection

`$i` will show the word of `i` iterator.

`${!i}` will show the variable's content. this is a **variable indirection**.

Therefore to check the content, you need to use `${!i}`

The solution is :

```
VAA="1st_first"
VAB="2nd_second"
VAC="3rd_third"

for i in VAA VAB VAC; do
       if [[ "${!i}" =~ ^[A-Za-z]*$ ]]; then
              echo "$i variable is a word"
       else
              echo "$i variable is not a word"
       fi
done
```

The result :

```
VAA variable is not a word
VAB variable is not a word
VAC variable is not a word
```